# Confused with implement Gestures

Tags: javascript, react-native, gesture

I Confused with the implementation of Gestures I see many repositries about that but didn't run with me.

I find some repositries in Github but the Animation didn't stop .. if somebody have alternative solution it will be very helpful.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  fadeValue: new Animated.Value(0),
  xValue: new Animated.Value(0),
  springValue: new Animated.Value(0.5),
  rotateValue: new Animated.Value(0),
}}
```

`
The animation didn't stop when I released.

Comment: Please post the entire code.